# IOS Swift ongoing notifications

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I wanted to know if it is possible to create ongoing notifications in IOS similar to the ones in Android. I have seen e.g. with Voice Recording applications, that after pressing record, the user can click the home button and red bar covers the top bar (same thing if the user is on a call).

I want to create a stop-watch with the additional functionality of the top bar ongoing notification so that the user knows that the stopwatch is running.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the status bar is not possible.

The best you can achieve is with a widget, where you can start/stop your stopwatch, etc. Starting with iOS 10, you can have rich notifications as well, but they still have to be triggered by the user, and I don't think that fits what you need.

Comment: how are the voice recording apps showing the notification ? I am not sure it is a classic notification, but the modification of the status bar.

Comment: Background access to the microphone shows the privacy bar automatically. This is not something that the app does, or indeed something that the app can choose not to do. It is shown by iOS

Comment: So it system controlled? As long as the microphone is listening it shows the app which is using it?

Comment: Yes, it is system controlled, and there are only few scenarios where the system does it - background location, call and voice recording.